# Accessing methods form nested classes using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I have the below class which is auto-generated by LeanFT Automation tool when an Object repository is created. Below is a condensed version of the file just to give an idea:

```
public class Calculator extends AppModelBase {
    private CalculatorWindow CalculatorWindow;

    public Calculator() throws GeneralLeanFtException {
        CalculatorWindow = new CalculatorWindow(this);
    }

    public CalculatorWindow CalculatorWindow() {
        return CalculatorWindow;
    }

    //Inner class   
    public class CalculatorWindow extends WindowNodeBase {
        private Button4 Button4;

        public CalculatorWindow(AppModelBase applicationModel) throws GeneralLeanFtException {
            Button4 = new Button4(this, applicationModel);
        }

        public Button4 Button4() {
            return Button4;
        }

        //Inner class
        public class Button4 extends ButtonNodeBase {
            public Button4(TestObject parent, AppModelBase applicationModel) throws GeneralLeanFtException {
                super(parent, applicationModel);
                setDisplayName("Button4");
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

As you can see, the Calculator class contains an inner class CalculatorWindow, which in turn contains an inner class Button4.

Within this project, in another class I can do something like -

```
Calculator caclModel = new Calculator();
caclModel.CalculatorWindow().Button4().click();
```

Now, I need to access the members of this class from a different project using Reflection. So far below is what I have:

```
        File file = new File("C:/TestProj/target/classes");
        URL classUrl = file.toURL();
        URL[] cUrls = new URL[] { classUrl };

        File sdkJar = new File("C:/Jars/14.0.0/sdk-14.0.0.JAR");
        URL parentUrl = sdkJar.toURL();
        URL[] pUrls = new URL[] { parentUrl };

        // Load jar
        URLClassLoader parentCL = new URLClassLoader(pUrls, LoaderTest.class.getClassLoader());

        // Load target class
        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(cUrls, parentCL);
        Class<?> clsCalc = cl.loadClass("Calculator");
        Object oCalc = clsCalc.newInstance();

        Class<?> clsApp = parentCL.loadClass("com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.AppModelBase");

        Class<?> clsWin = cl.loadClass("Calculator$CalculatorWindow");
        Constructor<?> cWin = clsWin.getDeclaredConstructor(clsCalc, clsApp);  

        // --> Works fine so far. After this, I should be able to do something like -
        //     oCalc.CalculatorWindow().Button4().click();
        //     Tried the below
        Object oWin = cWin.newInstance(oCalc); // throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

        // Class<?> clsBut = cl.loadClass("Calculator$CalculatorWindow$Button4");
        // Constructor<?> cBut = clsBut.getDeclaredConstructor(clsWin);
        //
        // Method click = clsBut.getDeclaredMethod("click");
        // click.invoke(cBut, null);
```

What is the correct approach to access the method in my inner most nested class so that I achieve something like `oCalc.CalculatorWindow().Button4().click();`

Comment: Is the class available in the classpath or not? Is it in some directory? Or in some JAR somewhere? You overload your question with details about LeanFT but don't communicate clearly, what the problem is.

Comment: What version of LeanFT are you using? In 14.03 they implemented a command line tool that lets you generate the AppModel file using just the `.tsrx` file.

Comment: @lexicore: Please see the updated question. I was able to get through the initial issue with loading the class files.

Comment: `getDeclaredConstructor(clsCalc)` searches for no-arg constructor. Your class does not have one. You have to search for `getDeclaredConstructor(clsCalc, AppModelBase.class)`.

Comment: @Adelin: I am using 14.0 version. So I won't be able to use that tool. However, I think I would still need to use reflection to access the class methods even in that case as I will need to load that file dynamically in my other project based on the .tsrx file.

Comment: @lexicore: Ok, I corrected that and it gets through. But when I try to get a new instance, it throws exception. Pls see edited question.

Comment: @Cdeez Well, *obviously* you have to pass an instance of `AppModelBase` as an argument to the constructor. The exception tells you precisely this.

Comment: @lexicore thanks for all the pointers. I was finally able to have my whole program running. I will post the final version of the code as an answer to serve as reference for anyone facing similar issue in future.